# Do need to solder on the pin headers panels on the edges of a protoboard or can I just attach them without solder?

Tags: arduino, soldering, protoboard

I have my first circuit on an Arduino Protoboard, and I was wondering if I had to solder the header pins to the board like the other components?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any pictures of what you are referring to? I have no idea what a seesaw is on a PCB - or protoboard.

Comment: If you are talking about [THIS](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-seesaw-atsamd09-breakout?view=all), then yes, those need to be soldered to work reliably.

Comment: I see your photo but which part is the seesaw part? If the contact point needs to conduct electricity, then you probably need to solder it.

Comment: I edited the post and added a picture of a seesaw, or what I know as a seesaw on a PCB.

Comment: if you're referring to the thing in the front of the picture, that's called a pin header, and it does need to be soldered.

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean a pin header, it does need to be soldered. Got it thanks.

Comment: I now know that Arduino makes a Seesaw, and I was using incorrect terminology, I meant the pin header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to as a Seesaw, is actually a pin header. Adafruit makes a [Seesaw](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3657?gclid=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ-1hG0wwii868UxZCSXgZ438QZEjrOu6KGYr9qaH16bjA6xF_1iC4CRoC4lcQAvD_BwE) microcontroller and you used the incorrect terminology. The pin headers must be [soldered onto the PCB](http://thesolderingstation.com/how-to/how-to-solder-header-pins/) (Arduino Protoboard) in order for the circuit to function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understand your issue, but every connection I see in your photo should be soldered for any sort of reliability.